# Make a multiple delimiter REGEX for preg_split

Tags: php, regex, pcre, delimiter

I need to split multiple lines in multiple files by different delimiters. I think preg_split should do the job but i never worked with PCRE REGEX stuff. I could also change all my delimiters to be consistent but that adds unnecessary calculations.

Q: My delimiters consist of (,)(;)(|)(space) and i am curious how to build such a REGEX.

Comment: I think because this is a very simple thing to achieve and if you looked at the PHP docs you would have found a [good example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#example-4677)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the characters in square brackets `[]`:

```
$parts = preg_split('/[,;| ]/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

You can also use `\s` instead of a space character, which matches all kinds of whitspace, such as tabs and newlines.

Comment: Thanks, i'm kinda flabbergasted how simple the regex actually is. Do the [] check for every character inside this? Kinda hard to find this simple info in the heaps of more advanced regex stuff.

Comment: @MennoGouw it's called a character class, in case you want to read more about it. [Here is a good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) that doesn't overwhelm you with "heaps of more advanced regex stuff" before explaining the basics very thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$string = "foo:bar|it;is:simple";
print_r(preg_split ( '/,|;|\||\s/' , $string ));
```